# VIM: opening files in the same folder as the remote file in current buffer

Tags: vim

When using the delightful netrw support in vim to open a file, opening directly works well, as in

```
:e scp://hostname//path/to/file
```

when I have a buffer open, I often need to load another file in the same directory that file is in. However, you can't change the working directory via

```
:cd scp://hostname//path/
```

And even with autochdir on, simply

```
:e another_file
```

doesn't work.

Is there a way of getting this or equivalent behavior? Key part is I want to be able to use a relative path to edit files.

I also failed to find a way (e.g. environment variable) to suggest VIM to look up relative `scp://` path with.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of editing a file with:

```
:e scp://hostname//path/to/file
```

you can list the parent directory with:

```
:e scp://hostname//path/to/
```

and use netrw to do the file navigation.

The `:Rex` command, allows you to open the last netrw listing so your workflow could be:

```
:e scp://hostname//path/to/    " list remote directory
/foo<CR>                       " search for a file
<CR>                           " edit that file
:Rex                           " re-list remote directory
/bar<CR>                       " search for another file
<CR>                           " edit that file
:Rex                           " re-list remote directory
                               " rince
                               " repeat
```